# Better way to clear input value with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

So I got stuck in this thought today...

What is the properly (or best) way to clear an input value with jQuery?

As far as I know, all these methods works just fine:

```
$('input').val(null);
$('input').val(undefined);
$('input').val('');
```

So, anyone knows a better method, or which one is the right one?

Comment: You can also use `$('input').attr('value', '');` or `$('input').removeAttr('value')`

Comment: This is a question that is easily answerable by reading the documentation, not by asking on SO.

Comment: What is the definition of "best"?

Comment: Following your thought, @Adam, you should start negativating half of all questions around stackoverflow. Thanks for the *relevant* comment thought.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the [`.val() API Documentation`](http://api.jquery.com/val/#val-value), we can set the values to input elements like:-

```
.val( value )
```

where `value` can be string of text or an array of strings corresponding to the value of each matched element to set as selected/checked.

So, the better solution here would be to use:-

```
.val('');
```

which is the minimal code out here.

Answer (score 0):

following both are ok

```
$('input').val('');
$('input').val("");
```

Comment: these are equivalent.

Comment: that is why i said both are ok

Comment: i want to ask downvoters there is no differnce between my answer and accepted & best answer then why to down vote my answer??

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
$('input').attr('value', ' ');
```

or

```
$('input').removeAttr('value')
```